# How can I write a Vba timer macro code that works when Excel is closed?

Tags: vba, excel, timer

I created 20 same `timer` modules(**starttimer,stoptimer,nexttick 1,2,3 until 20**).
It works so (at 45-30min textbox forecolor green, at 30-15min forecolor is yellow, under 15 min it seems red, at 00:00 it stop.) Everything is okay now. But when I close `excel`, all timers stop and `excel` gives warning to save them or discard changes. I need a `macro` code running when `excel` closed. Second problem I want to share this with other 2 computers using same network. Then how can I add `macro` for update module and give access authority to them? Finally I am new at `vba`. I did them with watching `YouTube` videos. So if you answer please make it so clear. By the way sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Your second question is quite unclear, please add some more informations on what you plan to do.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer for your first question this, it will activate before the workbook is closed.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
'Your Code Here
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi first of all thanks for answered sooo fast. Where Should ı write it ? To every single module , to worksheet1 or to workbook ?  And  my second question, ı will share this excel file with other 2 computer using same public network.And when they opened this excel file they should see updated timer.For example I started macro and now timer become 00:44:40,44:44,29... How can they say same datas with me ?

Comment: This code belongs in ´ThisWorkbook` . I dont know if thats possible. As you can share the same instance, you had to print the timer into a cell every second and if you open the workbook it would start from there.